# Best DataStructure to store XML repeating structure onStartup of Engine

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Spring,would like to know what is the best way to store a repeating structure on Startup of engine.

XML looks something like this :

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <OSNDetails>
        <Processor>IPL</Processor>
        <AddDataOSNs>AUTHORIZED</AddDataOSNs>
        <APIList>
            <confirmpayin>
                <osnlistwithDelay>AUTHORIZED:0,CAPTURED:10,SETTLED:15</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmpayin>
            <confirmrejected>
                <osnlistwithDelay>CONFIRMREJECTED:0</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmrejected>
            <confirmsettled>
                <osnlistwithDelay></osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmsettled>
            <confirmrefund>
                <osnlistwithDelay>REFUNDED:0</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmrefund>
        </APIList>
    </OSNDetails>
    <OSNDetails>
        <Processor>ABC</Processor>
        <AddDataOSNs>AUTHORIZED,REFUNDED,CONFIRMREJECTED,SETTLED</AddDataOSNs>
        <APIList>
            <confirmpayin>
                <osnlistwithDelay>AUTHORIZED:0,CAPTURED:5</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmpayin>
            <confirmrejected>
                <osnlistwithDelay>CONFIRMREJECTED:0</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmrejected>
            <confirmsettled>
                <osnlistwithDelay>SETTLED:0</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmsettled>
            <confirmrefund>
                <osnlistwithDelay>REFUNDED:0</osnlistwithDelay>
            </confirmrefund>
        </APIList>
    </OSNDetails>
</root>
```

Whats the best data structure to store repeating element structure and how to use it later while processing actual transactions.

Comment: Best structure for repeating elements: [**`List`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase//8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: but how can i store a hierarchal structure like the xml in question here.Could u pls help with some sample code . Do i need to create classes and store these repeating elements as objects in a list of that <E> Class type. Is there any other better way in spring or java ?

Comment: You asked *"what is the best way to store a repeating structure"*, and I just told you. The elements of the `List` should of course be objects with fields representative of the values in the XML, e.g. a class `OSNDetails` with fields `String processor`, `String addDataOSNs`, and `APIList apiList`, or something like that. You know, **objects**, as is commonly used by an Object-Oriented language like Java.

Comment: Thanks andreas.just wanted to confirm the same